# Most efficient way to create a grid-look for my page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to create a grid on my page made up of tiny, tiny boxes - (say, 2 pixels height and width, or 2x2). I had a few thoughts on how to go about this - all of which failed in one way or another:

1. PHP using the echo statemenet
2. Javascript - my best option so far
3. Manually construct the grid to fit a 800 x 800 space (would take WAY too long).

Unfortunately, even my best option was quite slow. Does anyone have a better plan for how I could create a grid made up of tiny squares in an efficient manner?

Comment: What is this grid for? Knowing what the grid is to be used for would help a lot.

Comment: What's the purpose of the grid--data view, aesthetics, ...? I feel like purpose would play a sizable role in the solution.

Comment: If its just for aesthetics, I highly suggest Photoshop or a similar image program.

Comment: No, it's for a coordinate system. I need users to be able to hover over a part of the grid, and some code will let the user know where his mouse is. (Grid 32x, 45y), for example.

Comment: I don't want to advertise myself, but maybe you want to have a look at the grid I created for [my Game of Life](http://felix-kling.de/Game-of-Life/) implementation. It uses a canvas to draw the grid.

Comment: Checking this out now, looks nice.

Comment: Have a look at the milliondollarpixel homepage, they created a massive grid with `<area>` and `coords` http://milliondollarhomepage.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (grid.gif is 3x3 with border, see http://stuff.drnet.at/stackoverflow/grid/ for working version):

```
<html><head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function mm (e) {
  if (!e) e=window.Event;
  var o=document.getElementById('grid');
  var x=e.clientX-o.offsetLeft;
  var y=e.clientY-o.offsetTop;
  document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML=''+x+'/'+y;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('grid').onmousemove=mm;">
<div id="grid" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; width:800px; height:600px; background: url(grid.gif) repeat left top; border:1px solid black; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></div>
<div id="coords" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:620px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested with FF & Chrome (both on Ubuntu Lucid) only, but idea should work.

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for the nicely written code. Unfortunately, I'd like there to be some way for the user to select the grid, drag it, etc.. For this reason, the game that was posted above seems as though it will be my best bet (once I get it working -  as it's throwing an annoying JQuery error.

Answer (score 1):

On a 2x2 grid, I'm pretty sure you won't be showing any data. Even if you are, I think it'll not be inside each grid box.

So, you should create a 2x2 (or 3x3 with 1 pixel border) image in your image program, and create a `div` that you want to "grid-ify" and give the div a `background`

```
.gridify {
    background: url(image/grid.jpg) repeat left top;
}
```

Where gridify is the class of your div/span/what have you.

**Further edit**

Now, since you want to click and drag to select an area, what you can do is [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191009/create-a-div-by-click-and-drag) to create a div on top of the `.gridify` div, and give the new "clicked-and-dragged" div a background that is darker and transparent... That will give the illusion of the boxes being selected.

Comment: Yes, but each square needs to have some sort of functionality. How can I do this if I'm using an image?

Comment: From what I read in your comments, if you just need to send over the co-ordinates of the mouse, you can easily do that with javascript without needing to trouble the grid.

Comment: That depends. What soft of functionality?

Comment: I like waht Indranil posted; however, I want the user to be able to click on a coordinate, drag his mouse,, and have it select many coordinates. I want this to by an interactive page, and thus want for the specific squares to light up as the user clicks / selects them. This is why i can't use an image!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little PHP to print out a grid:

```
<?php
$size = 5;
$total = 100;
?>
<html>
<head>
        <style>
        .box {
                width:<?php echo $size; ?>px;
                height:<?php echo $size; ?>px;
                float:left;
        }
        .black {
                background-color:black;
        }
        .white {
                background-color:white;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<div style='width:{$total}px;height:{$total}px;'>\n";
$start_color = true;
for($i = 1; $i <= floor($total/$size); $i++) {
        $start_color =! $start_color;
        $current_color = $start_color;
        for($j = 1; $j <= floor($total/$size); $j++) {
                echo "<span class='box ".(($current_color) ? 'black' : 'white')."' id='box_{$i}_{$j}'></span>\n";
                $current_color =! $current_color;
        }
}
echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Done this, far too inefficient for my liking.

Comment: Here's the problem: anything that is "too inefficient" to be created in a loop in PHP will be WAY too much for any browser to handle.

For example, for your 800x800 grid of 2x2 pixels, you're looking at 400x400 = 163,840,000 individual HTML elements.  That is too many to have any real purpose, as if you did something simple like apply a mouseOver event to each of them, any browser would barf.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the masonry jQuery plugin. Unfortunatley it's goal is to rearrange and animate a grid layout and not to print a tiny 2d layout but maybe it helps. It can also define a function for each of your brick or cell. It's algorithm is similar to the bin-packing.